# Chrome paused on exception within a try/catch block, how to auto resume?

Tags: jquery, debugging, google-chrome

I'm using PrimeFaces (3.2), but the question is related to Chrome I think.

Everything is ok unless I opened the Chrome debug window. I.e., if I close the debug window, no error occurred, no exception at all (see below, exception is try/catch-ed).

However, if I openned the Chrome debug window, and do something with the web page, then the debugger paused at following location:

```
if ( !Sizzle.isXML( node ) ) {
    try { 
        if ( pseudoWorks || !Expr.match.PSEUDO.test( expr ) && !/!=/.test( expr ) ) {
            var ret = matches.call( node, expr ); <----- Paused here.

            // IE 9's matchesSelector returns false on disconnected nodes
            if ( ret || !disconnectedMatch ||
                    // As well, disconnected nodes are said to be in a document
                    // fragment in IE 9, so check for that
                    node.document && node.document.nodeType !== 11 ) {
                return ret;
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

Here node=`<div ...` and expr=`:hidden`.
After investigated to the jQuery source code, it seems Chrome don't support `node.querySelectorAll(':hidden'),`.

Why Chrome will pause here, in the try/catch block? And how to make it not pause any more?

Chrome version: 17

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you unknowingly enabled "pause on exceptions" option in the Scripts tab of the Developer Console?  It's the fourth icon from the left in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

If the icon is highlighted blue, that means it's enabled, and any exceptions will cause the script to pause as if you'd set a breakpoint there, so you can debug it.